# How to mimic the custom NavigationBar item in Podcasts app

Tags: swift, uikit, uinavigationbar

The iPhone iOS podcast app has a trailing bar button item that behaves differently than most UIBarButtons. You can see it on the Listen Now page. It's the button on the top right that takes you to the account page. It is lower than normal, and it's inline with the title of the NavigationBar, and it is bigger than normal. Most importantly it scrolls up with the navigation title and disappears under the compact Navigation Bar. (The App Store app has the same behavior on the "Search", "Games" and "Apps" tabs.

Does anybody know how to get this behavior in either SwiftUI or UIKit? I haven't seen anyone else reproduce this and I wonder if this is something that only Apple has access to.

Comment: This is not a native effect. The closest open source version implementation I’ve seen is this https://www.uptech.team/blog/build-resizing-image-in-navigation-bar-with-large-title I don’t think this is how it was implemented in Podcasts though.